# unable to update

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got the below code, which i have a problem with.
I'm unable to calculate the 'total' amount on any instances of 'Labouritems' apart from the first instance, each on after that i'm not getting it to calculate.

```
var LabourItems = {
   rate: null,
   hours: null,
   total: null,
   init: function(object) {
      this.rate = parseInt($(object).children('.rate').first().val(), 10);
      // var rate = $(object).children('.rate').first();
      this.hours =parseInt($(object).children('.hours').first().val(), 10);
      this.total = this.rate * this.hours;
      this.updateTotal(object);
   },
   updateTotal: function(object) {
      $(object).children('.total').first().val(this.total || 0);
   }
}

//reactTochange for those inputs that you want to observe
$('.labouritems input').on("keyup", function() {
   $('.labouritems').each( function(key,value){
      LabourItems.init(this);
   });
});
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Btw, you should restructure your `init` method of a global singleton object to a simple `recalculate` function.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy: You don't create *any instances of 'Labouritems'*, you only have one `Labouritems` object.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any "instances" in your code, because you never call `new`.

To allow `LabourItems` to be treated as an object, declare it so:

```
function LabourItems(object) {
     return {
         rate: null,
         ...
     }
});
```

and then use `new LabourItems(this)` in your event handler.

Alternatively (and more efficiently, since each instance will share copies of the methods, rather than contain their own copy) use normal prototypical declarations:

```
function LabourItems(object) {
     this.rate = null,
     ...
};

LabourItems.prototype.init = function() {
    ...
};

LabourItems.prototype.updateTotal = function() {
    ...
};
```

and use `new LabourItems(this)` as above.

Comment: And it is very strange idea to pass `this` as param instead making a construction like `$(this).LabourItems()` ... any way it is a mess ... strongly recomend to see some examples and totally rewrite your code

Comment: @Reflective it's perfectly normal to pass `this` if it happens to be in the context of a callback.  Doing what you've suggested would only work if `LabourItems` had been written as a jQuery plugin.

Comment: That's the idea, hope you will agree that if an 'Class' executes on DOM element set using jQuery, it should be writean as a jQuery plugin.

Comment: @Reflective actually, no, I completely disagree (and I've written _lots_ of jQuery plugins).

Comment: you can do this functionality without even using an Object ... but that's not the right way ... i'm not talking about if this will work or not ... yes it will work ... but the functionality should be a property of the elements which operates on. why this class should be property of `window`? should be property of the elements which operates on. Don't know more clear way to explain.

Comment: anyone have an example on jsfiddle i can copy, i've asked this same question 3 times already and nothing works correctly. what happens is im inserting a new row of fields dynamically called labouritems and i need to calculate values across those fields only on that row.

Comment: @user979587 perhaps if you included some of your HTML that would help?  Better yet, create a test sample on jsfiddle yourself that demonstrates _only_ this problem so we can see the problem for real.